# Is the version of HTTP either 1.0 or 1.1 defined by webserver? How works the HTTP protocol definition?

Tags: http, get, http-headers, protocols

I have a quick question but in advance I've read the RFC 2616 Chapter 14.22 about Host and HTTP Header but I still not understand where in httpd.conf or configuration file of a webserver should be changed? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Look at following two HTTP GET I did to an Apache. The first one is GET for HTTP 1.0 , the other one is GET for HTTP 1.1. See the output:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 03:46:22 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_gzip/1.3.26.1a PHP/5.2.9 mod_throttle/3.1.2                 mod_psoft_traffic/0.2 mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8b
Vary: *
Last-Modified: Fri, 10 Aug 2012 20:22:30 GMT
ETag: "17c815b-3b-50256d86"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 59
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<body>
<center>webli7</center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 04:04:40 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_gzip/1.3.26.1a PHP/5.2.9 mod_throttle/3.1.2 mod_psoft_traffic/0.2 mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8b
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

16e
```

Comment: Could you post your GET requests? If anything, HTTP/1.1 should work better because it understands more headers and method types.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol version is decided dynamicaly, not through configuration files. The client send a request specifying the highest protocol version that its support. Then, the server must respond with either the version requested by the client, or any earlier version that it prefers.

Since Apache does support HTTP/1.1, it should therefore match exactly the version provided by the client.

There exist a flag that you may set in Apache's config to force Apache to use HTTP/1.0 in certain situations, even though the browser requested HTTP/1.1. This is used to fix bugs in HTTP/1.1 handling of some very old browser. Today, you should not need to play with this flag.

As for your error, I would suggest that you make sure that your GET does provide the Host: header. This header is required in HTTP/1.1, yet optional in HTTP/1.0, and having it missing would certainly result in a 400 error.